# Replace comma in database text column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I remove comma in  the beginning, in the end or in between two empty spaces?

For examples:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(max)=N' , test1 '; select * from functionReplace(@str) =N'test1;

SET @str = '1 , 2 ,';select * from functionReplace(@str) =N'1 , 2';
SET @str = ', ';select * from functionReplace(@str) = empty=N'';
```

Can you help me to write a function for that?

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output and what you've tried so far...

Comment: Hi Ivan, I edited my answer according to your edits...

Comment: Hi Ivan, why don't you answer clear questions? I finally ask you to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/5089204. Especially the last comment is pointing in the right direction. This question **is** solved, at least to the requirements you have stated initially. Changing these via "edit" would be a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer). So please clearify as asked or accept and start a new question. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Here you find a solution with a scalar function. The only difference to your expected outputs is the "1 , 2" which comes to a "1 2"...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.functionReplaceComma(@str NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(N' ' + @str + N' ',N' , ',N' '))));
END
GO

SELECT dbo.functionReplaceComma(N', this is , a test , with commas word1, word2, in between and at start and ending ,');
--this is a test with commas word1, word2, in between and at start and ending

SELECT dbo.functionReplaceComma(N' , test1 ');
--test1

SELECT dbo.functionReplaceComma(N'1 , 2 ,');
--1 2

SELECT dbo.functionReplaceComma(N', ');
--empty
```

Comment: I don't think so.  add "word1, word2" to your variable and see if the comma remains.  If it goes away, the stated requirement is not met.

Comment: @DanBracuk, just try it: only a `space-comma-space` is replaced... The OP writes explicitly "between two empty spaces"... Maybe the OP will provide sample data. That would help...

Comment: that is solve for only 3. case  but not for first and secund .
When comma is on end or on beginning of text,and remove only comma .

Comment: @Ivan, if you need further help I ask you to specify more samples (input->output). And please explain in a few words what you need this for and what you try to achieve...

Comment: @Ivan, I don't get it... My function returns exactly what you write in your question (`test1`, `1 2` [see below] and `empty string`). One exception: Your `N'1 , 2 ,'` is going to lose the comma between 1 and 2. How (which rule?) should the function know, that this comma has to remain?

Comment: @Ivan, really, I Do not understand you... You edited your question (just a few characters...), you did not provide clear sample data with expected output, neither did you answer my question of the last comment (which rule?). Also you ignored my comment before about explaining what you try to achieve. Now you took away the acceptance check... Why did you set it, if your question was not solved? So: Please explain what you need, provide (new/more) sample data, rule and expected output, and think a little bit with my head. I cannot magically know, what you need...

Comment: Declare str nvarchar(MAX)=N'1 , 2 , 3  , ';
Drclare Result nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT Result=reult from functionReplace(@str);
select Result; output - N'1 , 2 , 3'

Comment: @Ivan, in your question you write: "remove comma in the beginning, in the end **or** in between two empty spaces". My solution does exactly this... Your new comment doesn't clearify anything: This is invalid SQL, repeating just the example you gave before. And again you do not mention any rule, how this magic function should know, when to remove a comma "between two empty spaces" and when it should not. If you really want help, you'll have to invest some effort... And please, it would be fair to re-set the acceptance as my solution solves your given requirements for 100%.